# How can I use a custom payload name for my GameMaker game?

Tags: game-maker, windows

I have finished compiling my GameMaker Studio `.win` file. I then copied the `Runner.exe` binary to the game's directory to run it. The issue I face is that unless I name the game's payload "`Data.win`" the launcher asks me to manually browse for the payload. How can I use a name other than `Data.win` *and* have the launcher run as if it uses the default name?

Comment: How you compile the game?

Comment: I ran the game using the "Run the game" button. It's the green 'play' button located in the toolbar. Then I navigated to: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_XXXXX\gm_ttt_XXXXX\%PAYLOAD%.win` and copied the payload to the build folder allong with the other resources and the runner binary. Note: `XXXXX` in both of the `gm_ttt_XXXXX` directories varys per build.

Comment: It's wrong. See `File` -> `Create Application` (also you can change `type of file` there: Windows NSIS Installer, Single .exe or just .zip archive).

Comment: Already tried that, the payload is still named, _and_ referenced as `data.win`.

Comment: I believe it's not changeable for final result. Did you try to ask on oficial forum?

Comment: No. I'm currently in the process of using some old hacking techniques to achieve my goal. I'll post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: What the reason for trying to do this? Why don't you use single .exe instead, for example?

Comment: Namely to see how to do it. I suppose it isn't _necessary_, but what do you mean by "single .exe"? Is there a way to use the payload as the primary entrypoint?

Comment: Just try `File -> Create Application`, then change type of file to `Single runtime executable (*.exe)` and save.

Comment: That did *almost* what I thought it would, It compressed the game files into a `.cab` lossless archive. I debated doing something equivalent with a WinRAR SFX archive, but decided against it due to a slow start up from the fact that the files need to be extracted to `%TEMP%` before execution. I think I'll just continue hacking the executable, I've already made _some_ progress...